# I need help with my last 3 Discrete Mathematic homework questions relating to (ironically) Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I underestimated DM, I managed to solve 7 out of 10 but these three been bugging me for days and looking online haven't helped much, can anyone help me ?

Question 1

1. Suppose that A is a nonempty set, and f is a function that has A as its domain. Let R be the relation
   on A consisting of all ordered pairs (x, y) where f (x) = f (y). Show that R is an equivalence relation
   on A? What are the equivalence classes of R ?
2. Let R be a reflexive relation on a set A. Show that Rn is reflexive for all positive integers n.

Question 2 ( This one is mostly because I've been hearing many conflicting ideas )

Which of these are posets?

1. (Z, =)
2. (Z, 6=)
3. (Z, ≥)
4. (Z, the not related to symbol )

Question 3

Let R be the relation on the set A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} such that
(a, b)R(c, d) ⇔ a + b = c + d

1. Is R an equivalence relation?
2. What is the equivalence class of [(1,3)], [(2,4)], [(1,1)]?
3. Find the partition of set A formed by the equivalence classes of part b.

Thanks a lot everyone. Please help me get through my exam next week. Have a nice weekend guys :)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please delete this question, ask  three separate questions instead,  one at a time,  and show for each one what you have done so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: What is 6= suppose to mean?  What is Rn?

Comment: Do you know all of the definitions - equivalence relation, partial order, reflexive relation, etc?